# How to remove smell from plastic lid?

Tags: storage-method, cleaning, smell

A set of Ikea glass jars are used for home counter top food storage. One of them was temporarily used to store bars of soap. Now it is wanted back in the kitchen. The plastic in the lid is retaining the perfume smell of the soap. How can this smell be removed?

Answer (score 4):

Mix baking soda and white vinegar together (it'll get all foamy) and lather it up pretty well with the mixture and leave sit for a few hours.  Rinse and it should be clear of smells.

Comment: Vinegar by itself would probably do the trick too. Same technique. The baking soda is a useful addition when you're trying to scrub things, since the grit will help.

Comment: @Martha, I agree, when I save plastic containers from the store I fill them with a water/white vinegar mixture and just let them sit overnight; that seems to do the trick.